# Ionic Text field inside iframe doesn't accept input on iOS

Tags: ionic2

We have an ionic app with an iframe which host another web app. Everything works fine but we are not able to input values in the input fields of the web app(inside iframe). The cursor focus is there on the input field, but not able to type anything.

Note : It happens only when we run the app on device but it works fine in desktop browsers.